# String.split not counting the last empty elements

Tags: regex, groovy

Look at the following 2 examples. How to make sure the 2nd one prints 4 as well?

```
String s="a|b|c|d"
println(s.split("\\|").length)
//prints 4

s="a|b||"​​​​​​​​​​​​
println(s.split("\\|").length)​
//prints 2
```

Comment: if stringutils is legit do println(StringUtils.countOccurrencesOf(s, "\\|")+1);

Comment: May I know why this is down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the empty token, use split with limit = -1

```
println(s.split("\\|", -1).length)​
```

Answer (score -2):

Split wont allow you to have null values when you iterate. So the following code will work.

```
int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length();i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == '|')
        {
            counter++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: with 3 | would this not say 3 when the question wants 4? better int counter = 1?

Comment: The question relates to `String.split`, not counting the number of `|` characters in a string.